# Query varrendo todos registros

Tags: laravel

Bom dia pessoal, alguém poderia me ajudar nesse retorno?
Bom, tenho esse select:

```
public function Empenho($id)
{
    $table = DB::table('empenho as emp')
            ->join('gestora', 'emp.unidGestId', '=', 'gestora.id')
            ->join('gestora_tipo', 'gestora.tipoId', '=', 'gestora_tipo.id')
            ->join('despesa', 'emp.fichaOrcId', '=', 'despesa.id')
            ->join('pessoa', 'emp.fornecedorId', '=', 'pessoa.id')
            ->join('sub_elemento', 'emp.subElementoId', '=', 'sub_elemento.id')
            ->join('fonte', 'emp.fonteId', '=', 'fonte.id')
            ->join('cbo', 'emp.cboId', '=', 'cbo.id')
            ->select('gestora_tipo.nome as a', 'emp.nrEmpenho as b', 'emp.date as c', 'emp.hora_insc as d',
                     'emp.valor as e', 'pessoa.nome as f', 'sub_elemento.codSubElem as g', 'despesa.valor as h',
                     'fonte.descricao as i', 'emp.historico as j', 'emp.tipo as k',
                     'cbo.descricao as l', 'emp.folha as m')->get();

    $header = ['Gestora', 'Número', 'Data', 'Hora', 'Valor', 'Credor', 'SubElemento',
        'Despesa', 'Fonte', 'Historico', 'Tipo', 'CBO', 'Folha'];

    return ['Tipo' => 'Empenho', 'header' => $header, 'table' => $table, 'id' => $id];
}
```

O método get pega todas as informações, no entanto estou passando um parâmetro "id" que  recebe a identificação de cada registro do banco, então faço o mapeamento e o retorno do select:

```
function retornaEmpenho(json){
var result= $('<div>');

for(var i = 0; i < json.header.length; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < json.table.length; j++)
    {
    var arr = $.map(json.table[j], function(value){
        return [value];
    });
}
    var divInner = $('<div>');
    divInner.addClass(json.header[i]);
    divInner.append(json.header[i]+': ');
    divInner.append(arr[i]);
    result.append(divInner);
}       
    return result;
}
```

Tudo está funcionando normalmente, no entanto só consegui fazer o mapeamento de todo o registro, então minha variável "arr" sempre vai receber o ultimo registro, pois foi o último valor atribuído, o que eu queria saber é, como faço pra minha variável "arr" fazer o mapeamento somente do "$id" e me retornar somente os campos do "$id", alguém sabe como eu o faço? Estou usando laravel.
Grato desde já !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após a linha:

```
$table = DB::table('empenho as emp')
```

insira seu 'where' assim:

```
->where('nome_da_coluna_de_id', $id)
```

Tente com esse 'where' aí e substituindo 'join(' por 'leftJoin('.

Comment: Agradeço a resposta amigo, no entanto não resolveu, tentei dessa mesma forma que você me falou, também tentei assim:  ->where('empenho', 'empenho.id', '=', $id), no entanto ambos não resolveram.  Obrigado assim mesmo, continuo tentando.

Comment: O que retornou a query com esse `where` ? pode explicar melhor @LincolnBinda? Qual foi o retorno?

Comment: Tente com esse 'where' aí e substituindo 'join(' por 'leftJoin(' em todas as ocorrências.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas, tenho que esperar minha reputação chegar ao 15 para poder reputar, falta bem pouco, sou totalmente novato no fórum e ainda não consigo sinalizar como útil, no entanto agradeço em especial ao amigo Jhonnyjks por ter me ajudado a solucionar o problema. Grato !

Comment: Tranquilo! Cheguei ontem nessa versão PT do stack overflow, vamos contribuir e fortalecer!